# Display value instead of key

Tags: symfony

I created a multiple choice form, but instead of the values, the keys are shown, in the backend everything works fine,is it possible to display the values instead of the key, this is the form code:

```
$Themes[]=$options["data"][0]['Themes'];
$Styles[]=$options["data"][0]['Style'];

$builder
    ->add("Theme",ChoiceType::class,array(
        "expanded"=>true,
        "multiple"=>false,
        'choices'=>$Themes,
    ))
    ->add("Style",ChoiceType::class,array(
        "expanded"=>true,
        "multiple"=>false,
        'choices'=>$Styles,
    ))
    ->add('save',SubmitType::class,array(
        'attr' => array('class' => 'save')
    ));
```

In Twig I'm just using the start and end twig command to start the form.
Thank you very much.
Dump from Style and Themes
[image: Dump from Style and Themes]

I fixed it with an foreach loop, but i think its not the best solution?

Edit: Full Code

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RadioType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class DesignFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $Styles=$options["data"][0]['Style'];
        $Themes=$options["data"][0]['Themes'];
        dump($Styles);
        dump($Themes);

        /*foreach ($options["data"][0]['Style'] as $style) {

            $explode = explode('.', $style);
            $Styles[$explode[0]] = $style;
        }

        foreach ($options["data"][0]['Themes'] as $theme) {

            $explode = explode('.', $theme);
            $Themes[$explode[0]] = $theme;
        }*/


        $builder
            ->add(
                "Theme", ChoiceType::class, array("expanded" => true,
                "multiple" => false,
                'choices' => $Themes,
                ))
            ->add(
                "Style", ChoiceType::class, array("expanded" => true,
                "multiple" => false,
                'choices' => $Styles,
                'choice_value' => function ($value, $key){
                    return $value;
                },
                ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'attr' => array('class' => 'save')));

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {


    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_bundle_design_form_type';
    }
}
```

Comment: I might have jumped to conclusion with my answer :) Can you please show us an example of `$Styles` and `$Themes`?

Comment: hope the pictures are enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
$Themes[]=$options["data"][0]['Themes'];
$Styles[]=$options["data"][0]['Style'];

$builder
    ->add("Theme",ChoiceType::class,array(
        "expanded"=>true,
        "multiple"=>false,
        'choices'=>$Themes,
        'choice_value' => function ($value, $key){
            return $value;
        },
    ))
    ->add("Style",ChoiceType::class,array(
        "expanded"=>true,
        "multiple"=>false,
        'choices'=>$Styles,
        'choice_value' => function ($value, $key){
            return $value;
        },
    ))
    ->add('save',SubmitType::class,array(
        'attr' => array('class' => 'save')
    ));
```

I think it should work, but I'm not certain. It's an easy fix. The `choice_value` is callable.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm getting this error: Warning: Missing argument 2 for AppBundle\Form\DesignFormType::AppBundle\Form\{closure}()

Comment: Full Code is added

Comment: My guess is that both "Theme" and "Style" do not belong to an Entity. Is that correct? If so, you'll need to create your form in a Controller, instead of a Form class.

Answer (score 1):

That is most probably due to `Form` refactorization that happended in `v2.7`.

**Short answer:** Make sure you supply your choices in the following format:

```
[
    'text_to_show0' => 'value0',
    'text_to_show1' => 'value1'
    ....
    'text_to_showN' => 'valueN'
]
```

[`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) might be useful to you here.

**Long(er) answer:** You can read all about refactorization in form component **[here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization)**

Hope this help...

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I hoped theres is a faster solution :), maybe array flip could work, but then i have to flip it twice...